# how to get count of total number of rows following a group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to group some data and then count the number of rows after the duplicate data has been combined into groups.

data:

```
idx 
7706
7706
1000
```

want to return total count = 2

```
 select count(*) (
             select nb.idx
             group by nb.idx
             ) as test
```

First thing that came to mind was this.

and then I saw someone do this

select count(*) over()
group by nb.idx

I'm not sure I totally understand this second one, but I wanted to try various things and compare the speed of the various methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `count(distinct idx)`

```
select count(distinct idx)
from tablname
```

Comment: yes I just realized this. I needed the group by in the main query, but here where I'm just using count if I remove the group by clause then count(distinct) will return the total instead of the count of each group. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try below query..

```
select count(*), nb.idx from table_name
 group by nb.idx
```